# How to repeat tensor elements variable number of times in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have an input tensor which represents an alternation between item and item quantity:

```
[item0, qty0, item1, qty1, ...]
```

I would like to unfold this tensor to

```
[[item0*qty0], [item1*qty1], ...]
```

Example:

```
[1000, 2, 3000, 5, ...]

[[100,1000], [3000,3000,3000,3000,3000], ...]
```

This is in tensorflow 1.x btw.

Answer (score 1):

In tf1.x version.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.constant([10,2,20,3,30,4])
x_unpacked = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(inputs,(-1,2)))
tmp = []
for t in x_unpacked:
    tmp.append(tf.tile([t[0]], [t[1]]))
ans = tf.concat(tmp, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(ans))
# [10 10 20 20 20 30 30 30 30]
```

In tf2.x, it can be one line,

```py
tf.concat([tf.tile([x[0]],[x[1]]) for x in tf.reshape(inputs, (-1,2))], axis=0)
# [10 10 20 20 20 30 30 30 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

I started with the answer given by zihaozhihao, but since input has dimensions (?) the length is not known and hence tf.unstack won't work.

However, one of the error messages recommended using map_fn and that seems to work:

```
x_unpacked = tf.reshape(input, (-1, 2))
tiled = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.tile([x[0]], [x[1]]), x_unpacked)
```

Comment: map_fn is not working for me, it will occur Incompatible shape error.

Comment: Same here actually now that I tried running through a session :-/